# Check through Javascript that page is loading something

Tags: javascript, browser, loading, page-lifecycle

When the browser is loading something on a page you can see it in the status bar that it says "Waiting for..." or "Transfering..." etc.

In firebug you can check in the net tab when something is being loaded and see when it stops. That is what I want.

Is there a way for me to trigger an event when that happens ? Or to get the status of the page or something ? Any way for me to know when that changes ?

I know I can do this easier if I use Ajax, but I can't since the page it's expecting an Excel report.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the request for the page, do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'loading...';

/*
 * Load the object here
 */

document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can just use onload in the body tag... or am I missing something?

If you are trying to load the report asynchronously, why not using AJAX?